# Getting bbox filter to work with solr and geometrical data

Tags: solr

Let's say i have a newly generated solr core `coords` generated with `$bin/solr generate -c coords`.

Then I altered the fieldtype "location_rpt" to be usable with cartesian / geometrical data instead of geographical data using the JST-library:

```
<fieldType name="location_rpt" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType" maxDistErr="0.001" spatialContextFactory="org.locationtech.spatial4j.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory" validationRule="repairBuffer0" distErrPct="0.025" distanceUnits="kilometers" autoIndex="true"/>
```

Then I added a field to my schema via the Solr Admin UI that uses this type and is meant to hold points stored as WKT-Strings (`POINT(X Y)`)

I created three sample documents:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "indent":"on",
      "fl":"coords",
      "wt":"json",
      "_":"1485793578398"}},
  "response":{"numFound":3,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "coords":"POINT(0 0)"},
      {
        "coords":"POINT(1 1)"},
      {
        "coords":"POINT(3 3)"}]
  }}
```

Now I want to filter the results based on a bounding box so that the third point (3 3) should not be returned from the query, but the other ones should.

From the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search) I tried to modify the example string to my needs:

`/select?d=1&fl=coords&fq={!bbox sfield=coords}&indent=on&pt=1,1&q=*:*&wt=json`

This returns only one point (`POINT(1 1)`) and I have the feeling, that is does not come a a result, but is directly based on the `pt` parameter in the query.

How do I have to modify the query to query points in my bounding box?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody that is interested - i found a solution:

`fq=coords:[0,0 TO 2,2]`

so the full URL-encoded query would be:

`select?fq=coords:[0.0,0%20TO%202,2]&indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json`